# JDBC rollback failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

Tags: spring-boot

I have a service method that involves long-running SQL transactions. In order to prevent the SQL surge, we have set a query timeout in the JDBC template. However, we have encountered an issue where the database connection is closed due to the long-running transaction, resulting in a [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JDBC rollback failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed] error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are two timeouts defined. One for the query in the JDBC template and another one in the database or hikari pool connection definition. It looks like the later happens first, before the JDBC one.

**Solution**

Change the settings to let the query timeout come before the other timeout expires and the connection is closed.